# Loading a shapefile from S3 bucket with geopandas

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, geopandas

I am trying to read a shapefile from an AWS bucket using Geopandas and boto3.

I am logging onto AWS with SSO from command line, so there is no need to pass access keys.

My below script works when adjusted to load a Geojson file, but will not work on shapefiles and I get a ' No such file or directory' error from fiona

I am guessing this is to do with shapefiles been made up of multiple files?

```
import boto3
import geopandas as gpd

#S3 setup
boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name=profile_name)
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name=aws_region)
bucket_name = 'aws_bucket'
bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
objects = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='test')

# read shapefile from aws bucket
for object in objects:
    if object.key.endswith('.shp') and object.key.split('/')[-1].startswith('test_'):
        file_content = object.get()['Body'].read().decode('ISO-8859-1')
        shape = gpd.read_file(file_content)
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fiona\_shim.pyx", line 83, in fiona._shim.gdal_open_vector
  File "fiona\_err.pyx", line 291, in fiona._err.exc_wrap_pointer
fiona._err.CPLE_OpenFailedError: : No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to modify this script so it works on shapefiles